# Ajax - don't get Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a JavaScript function that I use to start a request. I need the GET parameter of this request, but trying to access it through PHP does not return anything. Any idea why?
I call the JS function in the same PHP file through which I try to access it (index.php)

JavaScript:

```
function aufloesung() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "index.php?screen=1", true);

    request.send();

}
```

PHP File:

```
<script> aufloesung(); </script>

...

echo $_GET["screen"]
```

But I don't get the parameter.

Comment: The html you're viewing in the browser cannot be modified by PHP, therefore the ajax request you are sending will instead return with an entirely new copy of the response from that php file, including the script. You then just have to take that text and do something with it, such as appending it to your page. It would likely be better if  you separated this into two php files.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy by using jQuery and slicing your index.php & ajaxphp files.

include jquery.js in your **index.php**:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    aufloesung();
</script>
```

app.js:

```
function aufloesung() {

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "get", 
        url: "ajax.php?screen=1", 
        success: function( data ) {

            alert( data );

        }
    });

}
```

ajax.php:

```
<?PHP

    echo $_GET[ 'screen' ];

?>
```

Comment: is this call correct: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>, between Code an src there is http://

Comment: your code is not jQuery, but if you want to use jquery in your page, you can use : `$.ajax({ type: "get", url: "index.php?screen=1", success: function( data ) { ..... } });`

Comment: but it depends. Screen can be 1 or 2. how i have to write the function to get back the right value?

Comment: Its could better to slice your index and ajax ( PHP ) file. i will edit my code now for easy to know.

Comment: i Wrote this: $.ajax({ type: "get", url: "index.php?screen=1", success: function( data ) { alert('hier'); } }); an it works i get the mesage hier, but php didn't get the value of "screen"

Comment: Sure it did, you just didn't view it. You're missing a fundamental part of XMLHttpRequests: the callback. Read the documentation.

Comment: Wow, including a whole library just to send a single ajax request? hah.

Comment: I know Kevin, he can use **Zepto** library for only sending ajax request. whats the problem ?

Comment: Why would you? XMLHttpRequest can easily do what he's wanting, and he's already half way there.

Comment: But if you see, **Stefan Gum** in above comments, wants to use jQuery ! . i want to help him by using jquery :(

Comment: thx Mohammad, i get the alert, but php didn't get the value, and i sliced the php file

Comment: Are you sure? i tested and there isn't problem and i get **1** value in alert.

Comment: @MohammadYekta — No, you suggested using jQuery, then the OP asked if what they were doing was right. The OP never asked to use jQuery (and the `javascript` tag on the question says you shouldn't introduce libraries like jQuery unless asked for).

Comment: @Quentin Please read #2 comment in this answer, and read my old answer ( before edit ). i didn't suggest to using jQuery....

Answer (score 0):

You are making two separate HTTP requests.

The first one made by typing a URL into the address bar of the browser doesn't include the query string parameter but is rendered in the page.

The second one, made by using the XMLHttpRequest object, does include the query string parameter, but you don't do anything with the response so you can't see it.

You could, for example:

```
function aufloesung() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "index.php?screen=1", true);
    request.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
        document.body.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(this.responseText)
        );
    });
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: i see the textnode, but php didn't get "Screen" or i can't see the value

Comment: Then you need to debug it. Describe the problem in more detail. Look in your browser's developer tools. See if the request is being made. See if you get the response you expect. See if there are errors in the Console.

Comment: the Problem is, i don't get the value of Screen, or i can't see the value. that's only my Problem, i don't get any Errors,